Error Extracting feature coordination into csv file
For context, I have a problem here in using csv package module, firstly I want to develop deep learning pose recognition with mediapipe pose detection. First thing to do is collect dataset of pose image. The dataset containing 3 cyclist position tuck, upright and climbing. Each containing more of 100 images.
Next preprocessing, done. I have resize for specific used and add grayscale each and every image inside dataset class. And for the error part is making pose detection, extract feature and save into csv file. All done but save into csv file throws an error. For keypoints is specific and important one require and features include coordination x, y, z and visibility score. That's all after extract those keypoints each with label column (label, keypoints.x, keypoints.y ..... keypoints.visibility) e.g right_hip.x , right_hip.y , right_hip.z and right_hip.visibility and this ill send an image . it duplicate each row and not in there respective row! (sorry if my vocabulary is bad)
Flow:

Collect dataset
Load , preprocessing and data cleaning
Making Pose detection
Extract feature
Save feature into CSV File (problem error here)

more
value each is duplicating in rows into the amount of dataset image available
example keypoints detects(specific)]
I am expecting the receive value of landmark in each correct rows and column, example I am referencing from https://github.com/NgoQuocBao1010/Exercise-Correction/tree/main and expecting this output :
At the last column receives no overfitting
Receive value in correct column of specific landmark and feature x, y, v
For code context , just ask me!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
